# How to properly handle double mutex lock in C++ version lesser than 17?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on c++14 version and I cant use `std::scoped_lock`

What is safe way to perform double lock on two different mutexes then?

Is below code safe from deadlock?

```
void foo(){
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock1(mutex1);
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock2(mutex2);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Apart from the answers given so far: If no C++17, but C++11 available, then you can achieve the same via [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock), see examples there. You could write your own scoped lock as a wrapper around – which I'd assume `std::scoped_lock` to be as well...

Answer (score 1):

> What is safe way to perform double lock on two different mutexes then?

Same as it always has been: just lock them in the same order every time.

> Is below code safe from deadlock?

It doesn't create any threads, so obviously yes.

More seriously, if this is the *only* code that can possibly lock both mutexes, then it's safe. If any code anywhere could try to lock them in the opposite order, that's where you can get a deadlock.

It's not magic, `std::scoped_lock` just automates the ordering for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely. It's free from deadlock provided all threads and code paths wanting to obtain both locks always acquire lock1 before lock2. Just as you have it.